# Areas feature in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-2.0

Asp.net mvc 2.0 is introducing Areas feature.  I am wondering what is the equivalent of asp.net mvc areas in ruby on rails framework? How rails handles the modules/sub sites functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the ASP.NET MVC definition of Areas, but at a glance it appears to be similar to the [Rails-Engines](http://rails-engines.org/). Although the intended purpose of Rails Engines, is to develop and distribute plugins as if they were mini applications. There's no reason you couldn't use Rails-Engines to achieve [what google leads me to believe is] the functionality of Areas.

Using Rails-Engines to implement Areas would mean designing each of your sub sites as a plugin. With some creative symlinking you won't even notice the difference.